# Aztech PlayXtreme ITV101E

Tags: ubuntu-touch

Aztech PlayXtreme ITV101E is an Android TV (with ICS: http://www.aztech.com/sg/playxtreme.html). Is there a possibility of installing UBUNTU in that? If possible that will allow me to break through a communication technology that all poor/orphanage will enjoy in Tamilnadu,India.

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically Ubuntu Touch could run on an android TV but, as of now, without a touchscreen there would be no way to interface with the device. I don't think Ubuntu Touch will ever run on your device because it does not meet the [minimum requirements](http://www.ubuntu.com/tablet/operators-and-oems).